# Read text file and fill in drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an Excel vba script that reads a text file (test.txt) and fills in a drop down list.
The drop down list has the following items:

Apple
Pears
Lemon
Lime

the text file has:

Apples
Apple slices
Big apple
Lemon juice
lemon
Pear slices

What i would like to get is when it reads Apple slices in the text file in the drop down list it is set as Apple. Same when it reads Big apple the drop down list is set to Apple.

Here i my code

```
Sub CopyTXT()

    Dim myFile, textline
    Dim compare As String
    Dim sArray() As String
    Dim mywnd As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dbsheet As Worksheet
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim x As Long

    Set myTable = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table3")
    TempArray = myTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
    myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

    Set dbsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = dbsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Charr = Chr$(160)
    myFile = "test.txt"

    For y = 1 To lr
        If Not dbsheet.Cells(y, 1) = Charr Then
            Close #1
             Open myFile For Input As #1
            Do Until EOF(1)
                Line Input #1, textline
                    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
                    If InStr(1, textline, myArray(x), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        dbsheet.Cells(y, 1).Value = textline
                        x = x + 1
                    End If
                    Next x
                y = y + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next
        Close #1
    End Sub
```

Comment: If I understood properly, your array `myArray` holds proper one-word values as in drop down list which are to be populated to worksheet. In this case if you match the input `If InStr(1, textline, myArray(x), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` with item in your array - you have to assign the value from array to cell, not the text line: `dbsheet.Cells(y, 1).Value = myArray(x)`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. that partially fixed it now in the list if there is zoete aardapple (sweat potato)  it matches the apple which isn't correct haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my first comment

> If I understood properly, your array `myArray` holds proper one-word
>   values as in drop down list which are to be populated to worksheet. In
>   this case if you match the input `If InStr(1, textline, myArray(x),
>   vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` with item in your array - you have to assign
>   the value from array to cell, not the text line: `dbsheet.Cells(y, 1).Value = myArray(x)`

And OPs clarification, I have an assumption that following may help, but it's too long for comment and requires formatting, so posting as an answer:

```
Dim z As Long

For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    ' in case there is a partial match found in line
    If InStr(1, textline, myArray(x), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' perform a word by word check of that line:
        ' put words to an array by splitting the text line with a space as delimiter
        For z = LBound(Split(textline, " ")) To UBound(Split(textline, " "))
            ' if one of words exactly matches the mask (myArray(x))
            If Split(textline, " ")(z) = myArray(x) Then
                ' then put it into a cell
                dbsheet.Cells(y, 1).Value = textline
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next x
```

But this won't work for comparison of Apple and Apples, need to think about this.

Comment: After i did split the myArray it started to work. 'For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)arrStrings = Split(myArray(x)) '